# Зависает страница

Tags: php, javascript, post, while

Вкратце: страница зависает (js перестает работать, не перезагружается), когда скрипт доходит до следующей части (JS):

```
var i = 0;
                                                    $.post("../php/video.php", {"upcmt": str},
                                                        function(data){
                                                            alert(data);
                                                            while(!data.replace(re, "$"+i) == ''){
                                                                var cmt = $("#cmt").val();
                                                                var acmt = data.replace(re, "$"+i);
                                                                var atcmt = data.replace(re, "$"+(i+1));
                                                                var tcmt = data.replace(re, "$"+(i+2));
                                                                document.querySelector("#cmt").innerHTML = cmt + '<p id="p-comments"><a href="account.html?'+acmt+'" id="author">' + atcmt + '</a>: ' + tcmt + '</p><br>';
                                                                i= i+3;
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    );
```

PHP (работает без сбоев):

```
  if(isset($_POST['upcmt'])){
    $idv = $_POST['upcmt'];
    $db = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'testsite', 'testsite', 'LHVideo');
    $jsc = file_get_contents("../json/".$idv.".json");
    $jsc = json_decode($jsc, true);
    $comments = $jsc['comments'];
    $cnt = count($comments);
    $i = 1;
    $end = "";
    while($i <= $cnt){
        $cmt = $comments[$i];
        $idp = array_keys($cmt)[0];
        $tcmt = $cmt[$idp];
        $author = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($db, "SELECT login FROM accounts WHERE id = '$idp'"))['login'];
        $end = $end." $idp $author $tcmt";
        $i++;
    }
    $err = mysqli_error($db);
    echo($end);
    mysqli_close($db);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас вероятно получается бесконечный цикл:

```
while(!data.replace(re, "$"+i) == '')
```

Если data.replace возвращает непустую строку, через ! вы превращаете ее в boolean false, а потом нестрого сравниваете с пустой строкой, что возвращает true. 
Если хотите сравнить результат с пустой строкой используйте:

```
while(data.replace(re, "$"+i) !== '')
```